# Correct form for: seated palms down dumbell wrist curl

Tags: wrist, curls, forearm, resistance-cord

I saw some videos and instructions on how to do **seated palms down dumbbell wrist curl** while sitting on a seat and doing it using a resistance tube. I found the following three differences.

1. The forearm, almost to the elbow, is touching the thighs.
2. Only the front part of the forearm touches the thighs, and the elbow doesn't touch.
3. Nothing on the forearm touch the thighs.

Which one of the above three is the correct form?
Are all three correct, and do they target different forearm areas?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Correct according to who?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov By Incorrect, I mean it could lead to injury or is less effective. There are videos of people doing this exercise using a bench, wherein the whole forearm is naturally in touch with the bench. And then I see some without the bench not touching the forearm completely till the elbow with the thigh